# Is is possible to mix the template and the link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, frontend

Suppose I define a custom directive like so:

```
myModule.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        template: "<p>hello</p>",
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.text('<p>something else</p>')
        }
    };
});
```

This of course is pointless; the link function will override the template completely. However my question is, if there is a way to mix the two in order to make something productive. Or if the moment I have a link function, I might as well get rid of the template completely?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific example of what you're trying to do? If you need some sort of advanced logic for setting the template on directive init, you could try this:

```
template: function(element, attrs) {
  var myTemplate = "<p>Hello world</p>";
  // logic here...
  return myTemplate;
}
```